# specify metaclass for dynamic type

Tags: python, metaclass

In Python, you can create types dynamically using the function `my_type = type(name, bases, dict)`. How would you specify a metaclass for this type `my_type`? (Ideally other than defining a throwaway `class` object that simply binds the metaclass to instantiated subclasses)

Comment: This is a little confusing because `type` called like this *is* a metaclass. If you have some other metaclass, it would be a subclass of `type`, maybe with its own `__new__()`. If you wanted a class of *that* type, you would just make one the same way you made this one: `some_meta(name, bases, dict)`.

Comment: @Mark Not true - that would skip the step of resolving the metaclass bases correctly.

Comment: Hmm, I'm sure you're right @wim. Having trouble coming up with a concrete example though.

Comment: @Mark A concrete example is given in [PEP 560](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0560/#dynamic-class-creation-and-types-resolve-bases).

Comment: Actually just reading thought [this source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7cba23164cf82f6619db002cd30021b5dfb1f809/Lib/types.py#L69) which is pretty clear. Thanks @wim.

Comment: Thanks to you both, learned something new from each of you. Credits all around :)

Comment: @Mark Just one other minor point about your first comment, it is also not strictly true that metaclasses need to be a subclass of type (see the second bullet point [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#determining-the-appropriate-metaclass)).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For [Dynamic Type Creation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#dynamic-type-creation) where you need to provide keywords in the class statement (including, but not limited to, the keyword "metaclass"), you would use [`types.new_class`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.new_class). The following class definition:

```
class A(B, C, metaclass=AMeta):
    pass
```

Can be created dynamically like:

```
A = types.new_class(
    name="A",
    bases=(B, C),
    kwds={"metaclass": AMeta},
    exec_body=None,
)
```

This is preferable to directly calling `type`, or any other metaclass, since it resolves the metaclass bases - depending on the types of `B` and `C`, the `type(A)` here [might not necessarily be `AMeta`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#determining-the-appropriate-metaclass).